# Comparing results to 50% chance with ANOVA

Tags: anova, interpretation

I've been having a difficult time looking for a solution to this one, though it seems easy enough. I'm trying to replicate an experiment (Fukumura, van Gompel 2010, JoMaL) which was constructed as follows. The participants were asked to write a continuation to a sentence. The continuations were annotated to see whether the participants referred to the first noun (NP1) or second noun (NP2) from the given sentence fragment. There were other manipulations, but one of the factors was the verb type (SE or ES, stimulus-experiencer or experiencer-stimulus, if that tells you anything ;)). There were no control conditions.

I have difficulties understanding how this part of the data analysis was performed:

> Following SE verbs, the proportion of references to NP1 was higher than 50% chance level
> (F1(1, 20) = 54.11, p < .001; F2(1, 40) = 99.33, p < .001; Min F0(1, 42) = 35.03, p < .001), whereas following ES verb sentences, the proportion of references to NP1 was lower than chance (F1(1, 20) = 123.68, p < .001; F2(1, 40) = 50.23, p < .001; Min F0(1, 59) = 35.72, p < .001).

The dependent variable was proportion of NP1 to NP2 answers and the independent variable  was verb type (SE vs ES.) The null hypothesis is obviously that the proportions of answers are at chance level but what data were they testing their results against?